# Oracle Developers guide 10g is not connecting to server

Tags: oracle, connectivity

I have installed Oracle developer's guide 10g on Windows 10; it installed successfully.

While connecting to Oracle EBS host data base it give an error.

Entered detail on connection screen:

```
User - myuser
Pass - mypass
Connect String - myuser@SID
```

Error:

> ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified
>
> Cause
>
> The service name specified is not defined correctly in the `TNSNAMES.ORA` file.

I check my `TNSNAMES.ORA` file at my database host machine. I found entry `TNSNAMES.ORA`:

```
SID =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = myhost)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = SID)
    )
  )
```

Where and what changes do I need to make in the settings file to connect it properly?

Host machine OS is Linux. Listener services is started.

Note:

`tnsnames.ora` and `sqlnet.ora` files are present at two places

**1. `C:\DevSuiteHome_1\NETWORK\ADMIN` - Path created after installing oracle developer guide 10g**

**2. `E:\app\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\NETWORK\ADMIN` - previous oracle installation path**

is there any catch in this file locations ?

**tnsping result:**

**`C:\Users\mymachine>tnsping mymachine`**

Used parameter files:

```
C:\DevSuiteHome_1\network\admin\sqlnet.ora

Attempting to contact (DESCRIPTION=(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=my_machine_name))
(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=my_ip)(PORT=1521)))
OK (20 msec)
```

**`C:\Users\mymachine>tnsping IP.32.88`**

Used parameter files:

```
C:\DevSuiteHome_1\network\admin\sqlnet.ora

Attempting to contact (DESCRIPTION=(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=IP.32.88))(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=IP.32.88)(PORT=1521)))
OK (70 msec)
```

Comment: You asked your question originally without creating an account. If you have now lost the cookie for that account (or are using a different device), you may be able to [merge your accounts](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts). In most cases, that is a very quick process, after which you will be able to edit your question without peer review.

Answer (score 1):

You said "I check my `TNSNAMES.ORA` file at my *database host* machine."  (emphasis mine).  The `tnsnames.ora` file is used by the *client* process. There are some other things to check as well. See [this](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/network.111/b28317/tnsnames.htm#NETRF261). But from what you've shown so far, I'd guess you are looking at the wrong file.  Oh, and since the nature of the problem means oracle couldn't even get as far as sending a request (because he didn't know where to send it), the listener never enters the picture for this error.